# What is PHP Data Objects (PDO)?

Tags: php, pdo

I am relatively new to PHP. I have written some scripts using Oracle and MySQL as databases, using `oci_` and `mysqli_` but now I am trying to understand what exactly PDO is.

I have read the PDO documentation at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php but still I have a few questions that I'm not sure on.

If I wanted to write a script to connect to an Oracle database I could use `oci_` functions, and then if I wanted to use the same script to connect to a MySQL database I would have to convert the script to use `mysqli_` functions.

Is the point of PDO that the same script can be used for any database, and the only part that would need to be changed is the DSN?

Comment: what about, doing some old fashion research and manual reading first?

Comment: Here is very nice tutorial on pdo http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2014/09/introduction-to-pdo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the point of PDO that the same script can be used for any database,
>   and the only part that would need to be changed is the DSN?

From the manual: **Introduction** http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

> The PHP Data Objects (PDO) extension defines a lightweight, consistent
>   interface for accessing databases in PHP. Each database driver that
>   implements the PDO interface can expose database-specific features as
>   regular extension functions. Note that you cannot perform any database
>   functions using the PDO extension by itself; you must use a
>   database-specific PDO driver to access a database server.
>
> PDO provides a data-access abstraction layer, which means that,
>   regardless of which database you're using, you use the same functions
>   to issue queries and fetch data. PDO does not provide a database
>   abstraction; it doesn't rewrite SQL or emulate missing features. You
>   should use a full-blown abstraction layer if you need that facility.

Comment: So ... yes or no? I read that as I said in the question. I don't understand.

Comment: Is the point of PDO that the same script can be used for any database, **yes**. The only part that would need to be changed is the DSN?... **yes**. But you must write query's to suit the driver thats the (it doesn't rewrite SQL or emulate missing features) part.